# Word Press Root Folder Redirect

Tags: wordpress

I am on a shared hosting, all directories in /public_html are redirecting to a single unknown url. I have checked all files in /public_html via ftp, there is no apparent malicious code. I have also checked each WP site db for injections they seem clean. Where else could I look? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: did you check your .htaccess file?

Comment: there is no .htaccess file in the /public_html dir